# ¿Cómo validar con JSP y servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Ayuda con las validaciones, estoy aprendiendo sobre JSP y servlets.
La duda es como puedo hacer para mostrar un mensaje si la contraseña en un login no es la correcta, en la misma pagina, pero sin otro tipo de lenguaje, jquery o ajax u otro.
O algun tema del que tenga que investigar para hacer eso
Por ejemplo tambien a la hora de registrar el cliente si el nickname ya está en uso mostrar el mensaje en la pagina de registro.
No tengo idea de que crear en la pagina JSP para que si hubiera error asignar el mensaje correspondiente

Comment: No entiendo los votos de cierre. Esta es una pregunta perfectamente válida para el sitio, puesto que el alcance está limitado a JSP y Servlets, sin librerías de JavaScript ni demás. Inclusive, esto es parte del proceso de aprendizaje de Servlets y JSPs. Los votantes Pikoh, toledano y Marcos votan sobre una tecnología de la cual parecen desconocer, así que les pediría abstenerse a votar en este caso. Es como si yo condenara una pregunta básica de python o PHP por pensar que es muy amplia pero sin embargo para alguien que conoce del tema reconoce que es simple.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

Desde tu servlets en el método doPost cuando detectes que se ha introducido una pwd incorrecta envías a la página jsp  una variable que  indique el error:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

         RequestDispatcher b=request.getRequestDispatcher("registro.jsp?
           errorA=Introduzca nombre y contraseña");
         b.forward(request,response);
}
```

Y en registro.jsp sera tu página donde se muestre el error:

```
<h1 class="errorValidacionUsuario"><%= request.getParameter("errorR")!=null?request.getParameter("errorR"):""%></h1>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64364/discussion-on-answer-by-alfing-como-validar-con-jsp-y-servlets).